# ActiveMQ Artemis cluster failover questions

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have a question in regards to Apache Artemis clustering with message grouping. This is also done in Kubernetes.

The current setup I have is 4 master nodes and 1 slave node. Node 0 is dedicated as LOCAL to handle message grouping and node 1 is the dedicated backup to node 0. Nodes 2-4 are REMOTE master nodes without backup nodes.

I've noticed that clients connected to nodes 2-4 is not failing over to the 3 other master nodes available when the connected Artemis node goes down, essentially not discovering the other nodes. Even after the original node comes back up, the client continues to fail to establish a connection. I've seen from a separate Stack Overflow post that master-to-master failover is not supported. Does this mean for every master node I need to create a slave node as well to handle the failover? Would this cause a two instance point of failure instead of however many nodes are within the cluster?

On a separate basic test using a cluster of two nodes with one master and one slave, I've observed that when I bring down the master node clients are connected to, the client doesn't failover to the slave node. Any ideas why?

Comment: You've got some legitimate questions here, but you should split the last paragraph into its own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you note in your question, failover is only supported between a live and a backup. Therefore, if you wanted failover for clients which were connected to nodes 2-4 then those nodes would need backups. This is described in more detail in the [ActiveMQ Artemis documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ha.html).

It's worth noting that clustering and message grouping, while technically possible, is a somewhat odd pairing. Clustering is a way to improve overall message throughput using horizontal scaling. However, message grouping naturally *serializes* message consumption for each group (to maintain message order) which then **decreases** overall message throughput (perhaps severely depending on the use-case). A single ActiveMQ Artemis node can potentially handle millions of messages per second. It may be that you don't need the increased message throughput of a cluster since you're grouping messages.

I've often seen users simply assume they need a cluster to deal with their expected load without actually conducting any performance benchmarking. This can potentially lead to higher costs for development, testing, administration, and (especially) hardware, and in some use-cases it can actually yield worse performance. Please ensure you've thoroughly benchmarked your application and broker architecture to confirm the proposed design.